# Windows 11: %USERPROFILE% not being expanded in environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-11

Both my colleague and I are debugging a C++ program on our respective Win11 computers.

We both have an environment variable in our System Properties->Environment Variables->System Variables `MYAPP_USER_DIR %USERPROFILE%\myapp` .

On my system, in cmd.exe,

```
C:\Users\me>echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\me

C:\Users\me>echo %MYAPP_USER_DIR%
C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\myapp
```

I don't even understand this: %USERPROFILE% expanded to something other than the value of USERPROFILE, which I'm also curious about.

For my coworker, though,

```
C:\Users\him>echo %MYAPP_USER_DIR%
%USERPROFILE%\myapp
```

It isn't expanded at all.  Why not?

Furthermore, when my coworker rebooted, it is now set!  Why???

```
C:\Users\him>echo %TIMELIKE_USER_DIR%
C:\Users\him\myapp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one of you runs the developing software or the executable it generates with administrative privileges.

This means that the program is run as administrator, and that means that the %userprofile% variable is the default: c:\Windows\system32. In your example it gives c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile which would be an indication that the program is not just started as administrator, but the SYSTEM user even.

The only way to avoid this is by not running the program in an elevated mode. This also means you cannot run as a service.

As for updating the system environmental vars, you need to write that to the system buffer and then restart the program in order to be able read it back. It is likely that you tested enough times that you actually performed that restart without knowing that it was that that was necessary to fix it.